# Mockito Junit testcoverage removal of unit test coverge

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

Hi recently we have done the unit testing for the entire project using mockito framework. My project is on Java spring rest project. But the coverage is below 35%. Need to improve the unit testing coverage.

1. Want to remove the unneccesay package from the code coverage, like test packages and beans class

2. Do we need to write the unit test case for the controller class and generated class from the tools.

I will be very grateful, if you can help me.

Comment: What have you already tried to find out how to exclude Classes from your code coverage tool? - And which one do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Test classes and packages are not counted in test coverage, if they were, how do you test the code that tests the code etc..

When you run coverage it should only run over src/main/Java etc.

Controller classes should be tested, when you call a method, is the correct delegated class and method called?

Generated classes, if from xml using jaxb etc do not need to be explicitly tested if they are just plain old Java objects with getter, setters and fields. It's likely they will be tested via another class that uses these objects and calls their methods. These classes will be generated/compiled before your tests run so will be available- make sure you aren't committing generated classes to your code repository.

You may want to consider testing the behaviour of third party libraries you depend on. This way you can instantly see if any updates to libraries may cause issues, but this should be from a high level.

Answer (score 0):

You need to not start ignoring classes, but instead run a code coverage tool and see what's uncovered, and get those unit tests up to par. Test your failure cases, too!

The test packages should NOT be part of the 35%, so removing them is not going to help. None of the coverage tools I know of consider test packages.

As for generated classes - most likely not, but again, run a code coverage tool and you'll quickly see what needs to be covered.

If you use IntelliJ then coverage tools are built in:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/code-coverage.html

Eclipse uses plugins, one is:
http://www.eclemma.org/ 
There are more if you google.

I prefer Sonar:
http://www.sonarqube.org/

But whatever tool you use, that's the way to go.